# Covalent and electrostatics interactions

Tags: energy, interactions, atomic-physics

I was reading one of the notes on protein folding today, and suddenly my eyes lit up when I saw one data. It was comparing different types of interactions with respect to their order of energy. It states that the order of energy of covalent interaction is 100-150 Kcal/mole while for electrostatics, the order of energy is 20-40 Kcal/mole. I am confused now, because Isn't electrostatics interaction stronger than covalent ? Am I missing on something or the note is wrong while stating these values ?

Comment: If indeed electrostatic interaction between the two electrons were stronger then a covalent bond would not have formed ever.

Comment: by electrostatic could you maybe have been referring to ionic interactions instead?

Comment: Aren't they same ? I mean ionic and electrostatic ?

Comment: I would guess the electrostatic interaction refers to hydrogen bonding. This is due to partial charges on the atoms in polar bonds like OH and NH, so it is weaker than the bonds in an ionic solid.

Comment: Nope, they explicitly says hydrogen bonding to have low value for energy behind electrostatics and above Van der waal.